# Magento 1.9 COD custom maximum order value & minimum order value limit set

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, backend, cash-on-delivery, zipcode

I was disabled default COD module. Now I am using [CashOnDelivery Based on Zipcode](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cashondelivery-based-on-zipcode.html) from magentocommerce. I need to add two custom fields **Minimum order total & Maximum order total** in backend. Through xml I was added those fields here the screen. [image: Backend screen] Now I need to process the condition minimum & maximum order total.

Here my CashOnDelivery Based on Zipcode module code.`

```
public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                    $result->isAvailable = true; 
                } else {    

                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }


                    if($isExist != true) {

                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) { 
                                    $isExist = true; 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false; 

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;

                }   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

`
Dear Magento Experts can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

### Changes:

*Instead of taken quote from session*

- `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()`,You cen get Qoute
  from event `$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();`
- validate the max and min value with Grand total of quote

> if((Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal()) <
>   $minValue )|| (
>                             Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal()) > $maXValue)){
>                             $result->isAvailable = false; 
>                             return;
>                         }

### Observer:

```
public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if($isModuleEnable) {

            if($method->getCode() == 'cashondelivery' ){

                /* Changing the retrive process */
                //$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
                $add = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode = $add->getData('postcode');

                $minValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/min_order_total');
                $maXValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/max_order_total');

                /* add max min validation */
                    if((Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal()) < $minValue )|| (
                        Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal()) > $maXValue)){
                        $result->isAvailable = false; 
                        return;
                    }

                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist = false;

                if(trim($zipCodes) == '') {             
                    $result->isAvailable = true; 
                } else {    

                    if(strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }


                    if($isExist != true) {

                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if(count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if(count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if($postcode == $codzipLine) { 
                                    $isExist = true; 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                        $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false; 

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;

                }   

            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I tried your code, But my entire module was not working, In check out page zip code condition was not working.

Comment: do you have pur [Your_Min_ieldName] fiel name?

Comment: Sorry Sir i forget it. Where can I find that field name. Through chrome inspect tool i got "id="cod_cod_min_order_total" name="groups[cod][fields][min_order_total][value]""